# (laravel4) pulling data from pivot table

Tags: laravel

I tried to refrain myself from asking a stupid question once again, but here i am...

So i want to check if a ID in my pivot table (tutorial_id) matches another id. However, i have no idea how to to get this ID from the pivot table.. this is what i tried:

Controller:

```
class TagController extends BaseController {
    public function getTutorials($tag) {
    $tag_id = Tag::where('name', $tag)->first();

    $tutorials = Tutorial::with('tags')->where('tutorial_id', '=', $tag_id->id)->get();
    return View::make('tutorials/tags', array(
        'tutorials' => $tutorials
    ));
}
}
```

Tutorial model:

```
class Tutorial extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tutorials';

    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tutorials_tags', 'tutorial_id');
    }
}
```

Tag model:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tags';
    public function tutorials() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tutorial', 'tutorials_tags', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

Database looks like this:

[image]
However i now get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tutorial_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tutorials` where `tutorial_id` = 1)
```

Comment: can you share the `Tutorial` and `Tag` models?

Comment: The question is, what you want as a result? And what is that `$tag_id->id`?

Comment: Sorry, i have added more information.
What i want is when i click on a Tag, that i get all the tutorials that have that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all tutorials with `tag_id->id`, you can do that like this: `$tag_id->tutorials`

I reformatted the code for you:

```
public function getTutorials($tag) {
    $tag = Tag::where('name', $tag)->first();

    return View::make('tutorials/tags', array(
        'tutorials' => $tag->tutorials
    ));
}
```

reference: http://vegibit.com/many-to-many-relationships-in-laravel/